# Creating a WPF control with a drag handle

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, wpf-controls

I'm working on a WPF data visualiser which allows you to drag SQL tables from a schema explorer (TreeView) onto a Canvas, and then wire up associations between tables. The Table control is defined in XAML something like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <Border Thickness="2">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding TableName}" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

What I want to achieve is for the user to be able to click on the TextBlock, which will contain the table's name, and drag the control around on the canvas to reposition it. Now there are [plenty](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx) [of](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx) [examples](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) on how to implement drag-to-move where the whole control is a drag handle, but I want to limit the handle just to the TextBlock (as the ListBox contains the list of columns in the table, and they can be dragged and dropped on to another table's columns to define the associations).

Has anyone been able to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented something like that a while back.

All my draggable controls inherited from the same base control. The base control had a `Loaded` event that would check the `VisualTree` for an `FrameworkElement` named `PART_DragHandle`, and if it found one it would tell my Drag/Drop code to use that control for initiating the drag. If it didn't find one, it would use the entire control.

The Drag/Drop code I started with is from [Bea Stollnitz's blog](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53), although I altered it quite a bit. I don't remember what her code includes, but I had a custom DependencyProperty for the DragHandle and could set it using something like this:

```
void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject control = sender as DependencyObject;
    if (control == null) return;

    var dragHandle = VisualTreeHelpers.FindChild<FrameworkElement>(
        control, "PART_DragHandle");

    if (dragHandle != null)
        this.dragDropManager.SetDragHandle(dragHandle);
    else
        this.dragDropManager.SetDragHandle(control);
}
```

To navigate the VisualTree and find my drag handle, I used some helper classes which I have posted [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/).